# HTML5 meter tag, changing gradient color using JS

Tags: javascript, css, html

I need to change the gradient using js by changing these percentage value using javascript.

Code:

```css
meter::-webkit-meter-optimum-value {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -5px #999 inset;
  background-image: linear-gradient( 90deg, #f44336 24%,#e6d450 24%,#e6d450 56%,#4CAF50 56%,#4CAF50 100%);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<meter value="1"></meter>
```

Comment: what part are you trying to change exactly? just the filled bar when the value is in the optimum region (green by default in Webkit) ?

Comment: I want to change those percentage values 24%, 56% etc to something else when I call an API.

Comment: why not just change the `low` and `high` attributes, from which those values are derived?

Comment: I need to control the gradient.

Answer (score 1):

With javascript you have to change the value attribute like this and add these variables to your style:

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName("meter")[0];
element.setAttribute("value", "100");
element.setAttribute("style", "--error: 10%;--warning: 20%;--ok: 100%;");
```

Also give your `meter` tag a `min` and a `max` attribute:

```
<meter value="0" max="100" min="0"></meter>
```

And add variables in your CSS:

```
meter {
  --error: 24%;
  --warning: 56%;
  --ok: 100%;
}

meter::-webkit-meter-optimum-value {
  background-image: linear-gradient( 90deg, #f44336 var(--error),#e6d450 var(--error),#e6d450 var(--warning),#4CAF50 var(--warning),#4CAF50 var(--ok));
}
```

So this should do the job:

```js
var element = document.getElementsByTagName("meter")[0];
element.setAttribute("value", "100");
element.setAttribute("style", "--error: 10%;--warning: 20%;--ok: 100%;");
```

```css
meter {
  --error: 24%;
  --warning: 56%;
  --ok: 100%;
}

meter::-webkit-meter-optimum-value {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -5px #999 inset;
  background-image: linear-gradient( 90deg, #f44336 var(--error),#e6d450 var(--error),#e6d450 var(--warning),#4CAF50 var(--warning),#4CAF50 var(--ok));
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<meter value="0" max="100" min="0"></meter>
```

Comment: I need to display the errors, warning info with this meter which I am getting from an API call. And I need to display using three colors as you can see here. The fourth color (gray) is not required to the client.

Comment: I'd recommend the `element.style.setProperty` OR `element.style[]` interfaces for setting CSS Variables from JS. (e.g. `element.style.setProperty("--error", "10%");` or `element.style["--error"] = "10%";`)

Using `.setAttribute` to set an elements' _attribute_ that in turn sets the _property_ of a DOM element, is a bit of a rollercoaster and considered bad practice generally.

Comment: I'd also recommend adding a warning/gotcha on cross-browser compat for CSS Variables for this method, just as a heads up: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables

Answer (score 0):

Just using JavaScript(document.styleSheets) you can access the style sheets and then you can find the backgroundImage style and set the desired values as below:

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(0, 0, 0) 5%, rgb(230, 212, 80) 5%, rgb(230, 212, 80) 15%, rgb(242, 143, 104) 15%, rgb(242, 143, 104) 55%, rgb(207, 130, 191) 55%, rgb(207, 130, 191) 95%, rgb(113, 159, 209) 95%, rgb(113, 159, 209) 100%)"
```